Node version in Jenkins pipline read from project's .nvmrc file
how to create jenkins pipeline that set's the node version defined in the project's ".nvmrc" file for the all stages?
For now the node version can be defined for all stages in a pipeline with:
tools {
nodejs 'Node_version'
}
When "Node_version" is defined at the NodeJS installation conf from the Jenkins Tools.
And editing the ".bashrc" to automatically detect the node version from ".nvmrc"file in directory doesn't helped for the shell inside the pipeline.
Reading the ".nvmrc" file in the first stage is successful and when echo the nodeVersion from the second is Ok too, but when try to define the version from the "tools" and run the job does not working.
Here is the output of the console:
ERROR: No jenkins.plugins.nodejs.tools.NodeJSInstallation named null found
Finished: FAILURE

And here is the script:
def nodeVersion
pipeline 
{
    agent {
        label 'test'
    }
    tools {
        nodejs "${nodeVersion}"
    }
    stages {
        stage('Setup node version') {
            steps {
                script {
                    nodeVersion = readFile '.nvmrc'
                }
            }
        }
        stage('echo node version') {
            steps {
                script {
                    echo "${nodeVersion}"
                }
                sh """
                node -v
                """
            }
        }
  }
}


Have you tried https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#readfile-read-file-from-workspace

you mean with the readFile from workspace?
Yes, with that part:
def nodeVersion
pipline {
agent{
label 'test'
}
stages{
stage 'Def node version {
steps {
script {
'nodeVersion = readFile('the_work_space_dir_path/.nvmrc').trim()
}
.....
tools {
nodejs nodeVersion
}

Can you try first printing the nodeVersion using the echo "${nodeVersion}" and then pass that version as tools { nodejs "${nodeVersion}" } Also can you please update this step in the question and the error that you recieved when you did that step.
